# initialising a delegate with a string

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Is there any way to initialise a delegate with a string? I.e. you won't know the name of the function that needs to be called at runtime? Or I'm guessing there is a better way of doing this?

```
   delegate void TestDelegate(myClass obj);

   void TestFunction()
   {
        TestDelegate td = new TestDelegate(myFuncName);  // works
        TestDelegate td = new TestDelegate("myFuncName");  // doesn't work
   }
```

**Update**

Is is the code I currently have which is not working

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bish b = new Bish();
        b.MMM();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Bish
{
    delegate void TestDelegate();
    public void MMM()
    {
        TestDelegate tDel = (TestDelegate)this.GetType().GetMethod("PrintMe").CreateDelegate(typeof(TestDelegate));
        tDel.Invoke();
    }

    void PrintMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("blah");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dynamic delegate this way

```
class Bish
{
    delegate void TestDelegate();
    delegate void TestDelegateWithParams(string parm);

    public void MMM()
    {
        TestDelegate tDel = () => { this.GetType().GetMethod("PrintMe").Invoke(this, null); };
        tDel.Invoke();

        TestDelegateWithParams tDel2 = (param) => { this.GetType().GetMethod("PrintMeWithParams").Invoke(this, new object[] { param }); };
        tDel2.Invoke("Test");
    }

    public void PrintMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("blah");
    }

    public void PrintMeWithParams(string param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a system null reference exception?

Comment: @mHelpMe Is the method static?

Comment: The function should be public

Comment: Or you should add `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` to *GetMethod*.

Comment: Try this 
Make sure to make your function public and use this `TestDelegate tDel = () => { this.GetType().GetMethod("PrintMe").Invoke(this, null); };
            tDel.Invoke();`

Comment: @CodeJoy thanks it now works. If you update your answer I will mark it as correct. If the delegate took a parameter would the above still work?